# How to redirect to Dashboard Screen after login successfully in react native expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

When I placed LoginScreen in Tabbed Screens then I can successfully login and navigate to DashboardScreen. But I can't navigate to tabbed screen when calling from outside the tabbed screen.? Please help as soon as possible.

Comment: Please add some code that you have done.

Comment: .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
     if (responseJson.res_status == "200") {
      console.log(responseJson.res_data);
      onSave = async () => {
try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("key", JSON.stringify(responseData));
        Alert.alert('Saved', 'Successful');
       } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'There was an error.')
       }
      }

      this.props.navigation.navigate('../navigation/MainTabNavigator/DashStack')
      } else {
      console.log(responseJson.res_message);
      alert(responseJson.res_message);

Comment: Please add code by edit question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to split your actual app navigator and the authentication navigator and create a simple "Auth flow" using a switch navigator like the following:

Login Screen example:

```js
class SignInScreen extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Button title="Sign in!" onPress={this._signInAsync} />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _signInAsync = async () => {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'abc');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthLoading') // after you sign in navigate to the auth screen
  };
}
```

Auth loading screen (Create this one):

```js
class AuthLoadingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._bootstrapAsync();
  }

  // Fetch the token from storage then navigate to our appropriate place
  _bootstrapAsync = async () => {
    const userToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken');

    // This will switch to the App screen or Auth screen and this loading
    // screen will be unmounted and thrown away.
    this.props.navigation.navigate(userToken ? 'App' : 'Auth');
  };

  // Render any loading content that you like here
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ActivityIndicator />
        <StatusBar barStyle="default" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

and finally on your App.js:

```js
import { createStackNavigator, createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';

// you can use tab navigation or stack navigation in the AppStack
const AppStack = createStackNavigator({ Home: HomeScreen, Other: OtherScreen });
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({ SignIn: SignInScreen });

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
    App: AppStack,
    Auth: AuthStack,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
  }
));
```